# Access to an object in an object from the template [Angular]

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have a "post" object, with an "author" property so that each post is associated with the author who published it.

The "author" property is a "user" object with a "name" property

What I want is to be able to access the "name" of this "User".

my json:

```
import { UserDB } from "./users";
import { EntrepriseDB } from "./entreprises";

export class PostDB {
  public static posts = [
    {
      _id: '5a9ae2106518248b68251fdf',
      title: 'Title',
      content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et nec putent quodsi, admodum assentior ad duo. Pri ad sapientem ocurreret incorrupte',
      link: 'https://link.com',
      author: UserDB,
      entreprise: EntrepriseDB,
      category: 'category1',
      tags: [
        'tag1',
        'tag2',
      ]
    }
   ]
```

```
export class UserDB {
  public static users = [
    {
      _id: "5a7b73f76bed15c94d1e46d4",
      index: 0,
      guid: "c01da2d1-07f8-4acc-a1e3-72dda7310af8",
      isActive: false,
      balance: 2838.08,
      age: 30,
      name: "Stefanie Marsh",
      gender: "female",
      company: "ACIUM",
      email: "stefaniemarsh@acium.com",
      phone: "+1 (857) 535-2066",
      address: "163 Poplar Avenue, Cliffside, Virginia, 4592",
      bd: "2015-02-08T04:28:44 -06:00",
      avatar: "assets/images/faces/1.jpg"
    },
```

html template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card mb-4" *ngFor=" let annonce of annonces$">
        <div class="card-body ">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-2">
                    <img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/binance.com" alt="">

                    <p>{{annonce.author.users.name}}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-10">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{annonce.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{annonce.content}}</p>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <a href="#" class="card-link ">Voir l'annonce</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link " (click)="open(annonce.link)">Voir le lien</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

properties "title" and "content" has returned but I can't find the properties of Users

more info: I use a template who has create this fake database.

Comment: `users` is an array so you need to either have another `*ngFor` or use some particular index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with another '*ngFor', but it turns all the names around, and I only want one and the right one lol. I can't figure out how to pass the index to it in particular.

Comment: Users is an array, so you have to do another *ngFor to display all the users. If you always will have just one user, you can do {{annonce.author.users[0].name}}

Comment: I have tried your solution. It returns a User in relation to the key sent. What I want is the "user" associated to this "annonce". But I don't see how I can tell it the right user key.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you for your help.

I've do that:

In the "AnnonceDB" class with different keys by "annonce:

> author: UserDB['users'][3],

Then I've called the property like this in the html template:

> {{annonce.author.name}}

and it's do it very well. thank you.